# Injective modules and prime ideals

Tags: modules, noetherian, injective-module

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$. We say that a right $R$-module $M$ is indecomposable if $M$ can not be decomposed as the internal direct sum $M=L \oplus K$ with $L$ and $K$ non-zero. Suppose that $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$ is a right $R$-module. How can I prove the following:

$M$ is injective if and only if $M \cong E(R/P)$ for some prime ideal $P\subset R$, where $E(R/P)$ is the injective envelope (or injective hull).

Or where can I find the proof of such a statement?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a proof in Lam's _Lectures on Modules and Rings_

Comment: So... are you assuming $M$ is indecomposable in the second half?  You define it, but don't use it...